# Ошибка при отправке Email

Tags: java, sendmail, javamail

Подскажите почему не отправляет е-мейл. программа запускается и не выдает ексепшены и не заканчивается. На другом компьютере идентичен класс работает

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;


public class SendEmail {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "*****@gmail.com";
        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "******@gmail.com";

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("***@gmail.com","******");
                    }
                });

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("This is actual message");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так все таки - "не запускается", или "не выдает ексепшены", или "не заканчивается"???

Comment: Простите, опечатка, исправил. Программа запускается

Comment: @KolyaTaranovsky Скопипастил код и запустил у себя - работает. А в ваших обоих случаях   использовалась одна и та же почта?

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok да, одна и та же